# How to disable Open_basedir() I have No access to httpd.conf or php.ini

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, ini, google-signin

Here is the following error:

```
> PHP Warning – yii\base\ErrorException file_exists(): open_basedir restriction in effect.
> File(/tmp/Google_Client/ad/xxxxxxxxxxxx.lock) is
> not within the allowed path(s):
> (/home/admin/web/xxxx.xxxxx.co.in/public_html:/home/admin/tmp)
```

Changed code in `.htaccess` like this

```
php_value allow_url_fopen On
php_value open_basedir Null
```

The same error is throwing.
Even added `ini_set('allow_url_fopen','on');` in config file.

I don't have access with my host to the `php.ini` file, so how can I override these settings? I've tried changed the settings from `.htaccess` file and changed in `web/index.php` nothing is working.

Can anyone help me out with this.

Comment: You can ask your hosting provider / system administrator to change the setting but realistically they will have sound security reasons for doing this and may not be willing to approve your request. Instead, you probably have access to a folder which is outside the site root but within your account's filesystem area, and likely to be accessible to PHP. You can check with the provider precisely which folders are allowed by the open_basedir settings in operation.

Comment: @ADyson the application is hosted in shared hosting that's why they cant give me the permission.

Comment: I know. Hence my suggestion above about how to get round it.

Comment: _"Even added ini_set('allow_url_fopen','on'); in config file."_ - the warning you are getting has nothing whatsoever to do with that setting.

Comment: The path mentioned is within the system's temp directory, so go and check within your app whether it offers any possibility to specify a different temp directory. (If you chose one below your document root, make sure it is not publicly available via HTTP.)